# display pairs of images using array of paths

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to load a bunch of images, split them into pairs and then display those pairs in a window side by side (pair by pair). Also I'm gonna add a button to choose which pair to display.

```
    def select_files():
        files = filedialog.askopenfilenames(title="Select photo", filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*.jpg"), ("all files", "*.*")))   
        # many lines of code for the algorithm that splits images into pair
        pairs.append([photo1, photo2])      


    root = Tk()

    selectButton = Button(root, text="Select", command=select_files)
    selectButton.place(x=5, y=500)


    show_first = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img1)
    show_second = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)

    panel1 = Label(root, image=show_first)
    panel1.place(x=5, y=5)

    panel2 = Label(root, image=show_second)
    panel2.place(x=200, y=5)


    root.geometry("%dx%d+500+500" % (550, 550))
    root.mainloop()
```

But how do I pass images to show_first and show_second?

P.S. in the line `pairs.append([photo1, photo2])` **photo1** and **photo2** are both lists with path stored in photo1[0] and image size in photo1[1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `tkinter` callbacks ¹do not directly support arguments and ²ignore the return value. The issue can be solved ¹using a `lambda` with default arguments and ²using a mutable object (e.g., a list) as said default argument, because when the callback function modify it the changes are reflected in the caller scope.

E.g., you can go define `select_files` with an argument, a list, that is a mutable argument that you *modify* at will

```
def select_files(pairs):
    pairs.clear()  # this voids the content of the list
    # many lines of code for the algorithm that splits images into pairs
    pairs.append(['a.jpg', 'b.jpg'])
```

then, in your main, you modify the `command=...` to introduce a default argument

```
pairs = []
...
selectButton = Button(root, text = "Select",
                      command = lambda pairs=pairs: select_files(pairs))
```

so that, eventually, you can acces each pair of image filenames

```
for fn1, fn2 in pairs:
    ...
```

To show it in practice,

```
>>> def gp(pairs):
...     pairs.append([1,2])
... 
>>> pairs = []
>>> (lambda p=pairs: gp(p))() 
>>> pairs
[[1, 2]]
>>>
```

and a counter example

```
>>> def gp(pairs):
...     pairs = [[1, 2]]
... 
>>> pairs = []
>>> (lambda p=pairs: gp(p))() 
>>> pairs
[]
>>>
```

that shows that you should *never* assign to the function argument...

Comment: _"The problem is that tkinter callbacks do not support arguments"_ - that's not exactly true. You can call functions that require arguments by using `lambda` or `functools.partial`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I edited my answer introducing the limiting adverb 'directly', what do you think?

Comment: I think the phrase "abusing mutable arguments" is a bit misleading and unclear.